# Multiple button click animation jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, button, click

I am beginner so please don't make too much fun of me, but I am having issues trying to get separate buttons to react when clicked. The current code that I have written will dim the all of the buttons when I click on only one of them. The problem is that I have 4 buttons and I want them to all be independent, but I don't want to type the same code 4 times for each of them.

---

Here is my HTML:

```
  <div type="button" id="green" class="btn green">

  </div>

  <div type="button" id="red" class="btn red">

  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">

  <div type="button" id="yellow" class="btn yellow">

  </div>
  <div type="button" id="blue" class="btn blue">

  </div>

</div>
```

Here is my jQuery code:

```
let buttonDim = function(){
  $(".btn").on("click", function(){
    $(".btn").addClass("pressed");
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(".btn").removeClass("pressed");
    }, 100);
  });
}
buttonDim();
```

I am aware that I have probably written the code ridiculously longer than it needs to be, but I am still learning.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try js buttonDim() like this

```
 $(".btn").on("click", function(){
  var button=$(this);
   button.addClass("pressed");
   setTimeout(function()
 {
    button.removeClass('pressed');
        
 }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: That worked for each individual button, but the "setTimeout" function doesn't seem to be working. Each button will just stay dim after I click them.

Comment: ok, now i'll try on js fiddle... Surely you have an extra </div> in your html but it isn't the problem

Comment: give me your css class 'pressed'

Comment: .pressed {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px white;
  background-color: grey;
}

Comment: i'll change the answer... it works.. please rate my question

Comment: I don't have 15 reputation yet so I can't rate anyone's answers, but I will as soon as I get to 15.